# Will the blank scales be cached?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tiles, arcgis-portal, mapcache

I am trying to cache the world map to the Portal on premises. There would be two layers in the tiled map services: worldcountries and oceans.

To compare the cache size, I first define the scale range of the worldcountries layer as 1:591,657,528 ~ 1:2,257, and the oceans layer as 1:591,657,528 ~ 1:18,056 (Figure 1). Then I define both layers' scale range as 1:591,657,528 ~ 1:18,489,298 (Figure 2).

In the Service Editor, I set up the levels of detail from 0 to 18. To my surprise, both estimate total cache size is about 21 TB. Will the blank scales in the second scenario be cached to the Portal?

Figure 1 (worldcountries scale: 1:591,657,528 ~ 1:2,257)
[image]

Figure 2 (layers scale: 1:591,657,528 ~ 1:18,489,298)
[image]